# How to detach 'dragstart' event from CKEditor instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

A little while ago, I was having problems with drag n' drop and CKEditor. Turns out there is a bug (not yet solved) with the editor preventing me from working with the `dragstart` event without reattaching it every time I destroy and recreate an instance of CKEditor. For more details on the bug, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899462/ckeditor-drag-and-drop-plugin-integration-stops-working-after-editor-instance-is)

By doing this, the `dragstart` event ends up firing more and more times each time I recreate an editor instance.

I would like to know if is there a way to detach the event as I am recreating the editor instance, so it fires only once (since I have to reattach it every time), just as a workaround until the bug is fixed.

I was suggested to do the following:

> You can put: `CKEDITOR.document.getById('contactList').on('dragstart', ... );` inside the plugin init method. After such change drag and drop should work, but dragstart will be fired multiple times. You can detach the `dragstart` event, before you attach it again end everything should work fine.

I have searched the docs and found nothing about it, so I'd be glad if anyone could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always keep the listener object reference, and remove it when it's no longer needed using [`removeListener`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event-method-on) method of object returned by `on` method.

See following example:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var myKeyListener = editor.on('key', function(){ console.log( 'key pressed' ); });
// Once you don't need the listener just call removeListener() method.
myKeyListener.removeListener();
```